# CPU usage for Symfony application deployed on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently trying to figure out a weird problem that is occurring where after a deployment is made to ElasticBeantalk (t3 instance running PHP 7.2 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.8.6), CPU usage and response times will continue to increase until around 40-50%.

We have a landing page that contains a login form.  If we point a Route 53 health check or LB health check to this page, response times and CPU usage will continue to climb until the server becomes unresponsive.

[image]

Apparently the culprit is any function accessing the session data.

- `csrf_token()` in Twig
- `getLastAuthenticationError()`
- `getLastUsername()`

If these are removed then everything runs sable, and we've only experience this issue when attempting to use ElasticBeanstalk with the default PHP 7.2 images.  Has anyone run into a similar issue?

**Edit:**
Currently using DynamoDB as the session handler.  As detailed in the following:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/service_dynamodb-session-handler.html
- https://github.com/gwkunze/dynamo-session-bundle

Switching to file based session handling does indeed remove the excessive CPU usage.  So the issue seems to be within the DynamoDB handler.

Comment: What session driver are you using?

Comment: DynamoDB.  Session handler based on one found here:  https://github.com/gwkunze/dynamo-session-bundle/blob/master/Handler/SessionHandler.php